# Which MAX3232 IC's for simple UART to RS232 converter?

Tags: arduino, uart, converter, rs232, ttl

I am trying make a TTL to RS232 converter.

I have designed my PCB for 16 pin SMD sop16 and max3232 CSE+. But when I was buying from a store ([store link](https://www.direnc.net/arama?q=max3232)), I saw other types of max3232. I've bought and tried a few of them and they all work.

What is the difference between these different models and which one should i choose for a simple arduino project. Also there are price differences.

other max3232 ICs all of them is soic16 and SMD

1. MAX3232EIDR about 3 usd,
2. MAX3232CSE+T about 1 usd,
3. MAX3232ESE+T about 3 usd,
4. MAX3232IDR about 3.5 usd,
5. MAX3232IDWR about 1usd.

İf I check other rs232 converter they have also use different chips.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You open the chip datasheet and there is a page which explans the meanings. Can you find it?

Comment: I cant see, datasheet for each of them. Please show me link

Comment: Which data sheet are you looking at, from which manufacturer?

Comment: Why are there different kinds of cars? They all drive. Same for different chips, they might have different features, they might not (EG. Safety features). Check the datasheet for what you need then pick the cheapest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**MAX3232IDR** and **MAX3232IDWR** are [MAX3232](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/max3232.pdf) parts from Texas Instruments.

On page 15 you'll find the packaging information (an excerpt):
[image]

As you can see the MAX3232IDR is end-of-life, so not recommended for new designs:
[image]

Both have the same operating temperature range: -40 to 85 °C

But their package types have differences. On page 1 you'll find the package information:
[image]

---

The **MAX3232EIDR** is also from Texas Instruments, but the newer [MAX3232E](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/max3232e.pdf) variant.

From my first glance the main difference is the additional IEC61000-4-2 ESD ratings.

From page 4:
[image]

Other than that it has similar specs to the MAX3232IDR:
[image]

---

The **MAX3232CSE+T** and **MAX3232ESE+T** are [MAX3232](https://www.mouser.ch/datasheet/2/256/MAX3222-MAX3241-1292123.pdf) parts from Maxim.

On page 15 you'll find the part specifications:
[image]

The main difference is the operating temperature range.

Here you can find information about [Maxim Product Naming Conventions](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/packaging/package-information/maxim-naming-conventions.html):

- `+`: Indicates a lead-free (RoHS) qualified version.
- `T`: Part is furnished on tape-and-reel. T or T&R indicates the standard reel quantity for the given package, usually 2.5K. T10 indicates a reel quantity of 10K.

---

As you can see, the necessary information is provided by the datasheets. At least when you're buying parts from reputable manufacturers.

Answer (score 6):

The suffix letters may indicate temperature ranges, package variation and other things, and probably vary between manufacturers.

Looking at Maxim's datasheet, the MAX3232C* parts are commercial temperature range: 0 - 70C, while the MAX3232E* are -40 - 85C. The remaining letters indicate package variations.

This sort of information is often hidden at the end of the datasheet.

Answer (score 0):

You need the datasheet for the chip from the manufacturer of the chip to decode part numbers.

The MAX3232 part numbers in the question are likely not from a single manufacturer but multiple manufacturers.

It seems that part numbers match parts manufactured by Maxim and TI, but you need to know who manufactured your chips to find a correct data sheet.